# Puppetelabs Vagrant Box password not working

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to bring up a Puppetlabs vagrant box and the password is not working.  Tried 'vagrant' and 'puppet'.  Anyone get these working?

Comment: `root` user has password `puppet`, user `vagrant` doesn't have a defult password afaik, but you can log into using default keys https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys

Comment: Well, then I guess it would be better to post my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`root` user has password `puppet` as stated in [repository of manifests used to build Puppetlabs boxes](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-packer).

To login as `vagrant` user provide [default insecure Vagrant keys](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys)